# How to disable WMP media switching on CD insert?

Tags: windows-media-player, compact-disc, autorun, autoplay

I am sometimes listening to something on Windows Media Player while simultaneously batch-copying CDs with another program. When i insert a CD into the drive, WMP inexplicably stops whatever it is playing now and plays the newly inserted CD.

How to disable this abhorrent behaviour? Autorun is set to “always ask me”.

I am currently using Windows 10 10041, but the problem appeared on Windows 8.1 as well.

Answer (score -1):

Please try copy/pasting the following into Notepad, save it as `DisableMediaPlayerAutoPlay.reg`, double click this file to add it to the registry, and restart WMP:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\MediaPlayer\Preferences]
"CDAutoPlay"=dword:00000000
```

This will however only disable autoplay in WMP's Library mode. WMP in Now Playing mode will still automatically play CDs when inserted, I don't know if there's a way around that.

Comment: Ehh. Found that in library mode it will not stop irregardless of the existence of this registry entry. Downvoted only because it gives bogus advice.

Comment: For now i will remember to switch to library tab as a work-around.

Comment: Apologies, I wasn't aware that the registry change didn't have any effect (it probably did though for earlier versions of WMP). Thanks for reporting back.